# from docker-compose to kubernetes as development environment using minikube

Tags: kubernetes, docker-compose, minikube

Right now i use docker-compose for development. This is a great tool that comes handy if i use it on simple projects where i got maximum of 3-6 active services but when it comes to 6-8 and more it is become hard to manage.

So i've started to learn k8s on minikube and now i got few questions about some questions:

1. How to make "two-way" binding for volumes? for example if i have folder named "my-frontend" and i want to sync specific folder in deployment, how to "link" them using PV and PVC ?
2. Very often it comes handy to make some service with specific environment like node:12.0.0 and then use it as command executor like this: `docker-compose run workspace npm install` 
   how to achieve something like this using k8s?

Comment: Out of curiosity: what problems to you have with the docker-compose setup that you hope to solve with minikube? (As there is no such thing as mounting directories into pods with k8s (i think?), so you would have to solve that via volumes, which is maybe not a good solution. Or you build images all the time, which is not convenient for local development)

Answer (score 1):

> How to make "two-way" binding for volumes? for example if i have folder named "my-frontend" and i want to sync specific folder in deployment, how to "link" them using PV and PVC ?

You need to create a `PersistentVolume` which in your case will use a specific directory in the host, in Kubernetes [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/#create-a-persistentvolume) there's an example with this same use case.

Then a `PersistentVolumeClaim` to request some space from this volume (also an example in the previous documentation) and then mount the PVC on the pod/deployment where you need it.

```
  volumes:
    - name: my-volume
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: my-pvc
  containers:
      ....
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/mount/path/in/pod"
          name: my-volume
```

> Very often it comes handy to make some service with specific environment like node:12.0.0 and then use it as command executor like this: docker-compose run workspace npm install
> how to achieve something like this using k8s?

You need to use `kubectl`, it has very similar functionalities as docker CLI, it also supports [run command](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#run) with very similar parameters and functionality. Alternatively, you can start your pod once and then run commands multiple times in the same instance by using [kubectl exec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#exec)

Comment: Note that the PV/PVC to replace your image content with host content winds up being very bulky; if you're not using many Kubernetes features otherwise, it will probably at least double the size of your YAML files.  It also just does not work in "real-world" Kubernetes environments that aren't running on your desktop system.  I'd avoid this approach (and probably avoid trying to use Kubernetes as a development environment).